# Xampp Not Serving Metadata Folder

Tags: gruntjs, xampp

My folder structure for my application in my xampp htcdocs is:

- index.html
- scripts/
- styles/
- images/
- metadata/

  - metadata.json

I'm trying to read metadata.json, but it's getting a 404 trying to find the file.

When I go to the sources in chrome developer console, it's only finding the scripts and styles folder.

**Note**
This was built using Grunt Build, but the grunt file includes the metadata folder & files, and the folder and files are copied to the dist folder.

Answer (score 0):

**First, the basics...**

Did you tail the log file of your web server and see why it's giving you the 404?

**http.conf, http-vhosts.conf, etc...**

I've seen some instances of the XAMPP Apache web daemon where the `httpd` service needs to be restarted in order for it to serve any files that might get created after startup, especially dynamically generated root directory paths. This is done as a security precaution.

**If you're still having issues...**

You may also need to make sure the your Apache *http.conf* files define a document type for the `JSON` MIME type. Also, you may need to explicitly allow public access to the new *metadata* directory, since it is a new root namespace.

**A quick and dirty fix** (not recommended)

Use `.htaccess` files, if you don't want to touch your Apache configurations. **But, never do this in a production environment!**

Hope that helps.